# Installation of f90wrap on Windows 10 (64)

Tags: python, installation, pip, conda

I have some problems with the installation of f90wrap on win 10. I installed python 3 via conda. Unfortionately conda supplies f90wrap only for linux and osx :(. The installation with pip run in to an error: Command "Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview" failed with exit status 1112.
Also found no answer in the forum or web. 
thx for your help!
BG
maths

Comment: You're not the only one with similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361123/f90wrap-on-windows-python-wrapper-for-fortran-90 and check https://synchroversum.wordpress.com/2016/03/03/windows-f2py-f90wrap-mingw-gfortran/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more recent answer that I was able to use
https://github.com/jameskermode/f90wrap/issues/149

Short summary
I got f90wrap to work on Windows 10 (64 bit, home edition) with Anaconda Python 3.8.8, numpy version 1.20.1 and f90wrap 0.2.7; gfortran through mingw-w64 (v8.1.0). I built f90wrap with python setup.py install after telling distutils.cfg to use mingw32 (and not the microsoft visual c/c++ compiler)